# как вывести json с вложенными массивами

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

апи бинанса, к сожалению не идеально и порой есть моменты, когда вместо нормальных вариантов с массивом объектов, из запроса прилетает массив массивов. с этим я и столкнулся. и это кинуло меня в ступор.

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

 const requireOrders = () => axios.get(https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?limit=10&symbol=BTCUSDT)
        .then(order => {
            console.log(order.data.bids);
            setOrders(order.data.bids);
            setIsLoadedOrders(true);
            setTimeout(() => requireData(), 1000)
        })

    const [price, qty] = orders;

    useEffect(() => {
        requireOrders();
    }, []);

{isLoadedOrders ? orders.map(array => <Order price={array.price} qty={array.qty}  />) : "загрузка"}
```

```
Array(10) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […] ]
​
0: Array [ "19846.96000000", "0.02276000" ]
​
1: Array [ "19846.95000000", "0.25193000" ]
​
2: Array [ "19846.94000000", "0.00680000" ]
​
3: Array [ "19846.91000000", "0.00051000" ]
​
4: Array [ "19846.88000000", "0.04119000" ]
​
5: Array [ "19846.87000000", "0.00053000" ]
​
6: Array [ "19846.84000000", "0.68228000" ]
​
7: Array [ "19846.83000000", "1.59320000" ]
​
8: Array [ "19846.80000000", "0.05138000" ]
​
9: Array [ "19846.79000000", "0.01000000" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

поправка:
нашел решение
в мапе прописать следующее:

```
{isLoadedOrders ?  orders.map(order => {const [price, qty] = order;return <Order price={price} qty={qty} /> }) : "загрузка"}
```